# Azure LDAP settings

Tags: ldap, azure-active-directory

I am looking for the LDAP settings I would use to access Azure AD.  We do not use AD on premise, AD FS, nor the Azure AD Connector.  I have a 3rd party application, zixcorp, that can utilize azure ad security groups.  Settings I have found and I assume I can use would be;

Username & Password;  I have configured in AD Azure users.

Domain:  mydomain-com.protection.office.com ...possibly mydomain-com.ldap.protection.office.com

Port: 389 or 636

Search Base:  ????  Not sure what to enter  here

Domain:  ?????  office.com?  Not sure here either.

Any help would be appreciated.  thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure AD, by itself, does not expose any LDAP endpoints. Azure AD is *not* Windows Server Active Directory, running on Azure.

If your application absolutely positively *must*  use LDAP(S) (rather than the REST API or group claims), then you can deploy [Azure AD Domain Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-overview). This will sync your Azure AD tenant into a managed Window Server AD deployment which you can access via LDAP(S) for read operations: [Configure secure LDAP for an Azure AD Domain Services managed domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/active-directory-ds-admin-guide-configure-secure-ldap).

Comment: Thank  you.   Just what I was looking for.